# cpanel account transfers failing: ERROR: Failed to dump one or more databases

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

Getting this error when transferring multiple accounts via whm transfer utility:

ERROR: Failed to dump one or more databases

I was told this by a cpanel tech

```
Here is the specific error I'm seeing on some of the accounts:

warn [pkgacct] eli_test: mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'bak_components'; try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES

You may need to try to repair these tables as suggested in the error. After some further research I see you're using myisam, so you may want to use the myisam check and repair as well:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-repair-corrupted-mysql-tables-using-myisamchk/
```

I've already ran this:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases -r
mysqlcheck --all-databases -a
mysqlcheck --all-databases -o
```

Also, I even re-attempted to transfer with mysql stopped, but got this:

```
Determining mysql dbs.../usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
```

I tried repairing mysiam:

```
root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/e*/*.MYI
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/edisecur_joom/user_core_acl_aro.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/edisecur_joom/user_session.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 10 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/eximstats/sends.MYI
myisamchk: warning: Table is marked as crashed
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: error: Found 138761 keys of 138908
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/eximstats/smtp.MYI
myisamchk: warning: Table is marked as crashed and last repair failed
myisamchk: Unknown error 126
myisamchk: error: Can't read indexpage from filepos: -1


root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/i*/*.MYI
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/impact_joom/j25_content.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/impact_joom/j25_session.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly


root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/k*/*.MYI
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/korol_joom/user_core_acl_aro.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 3 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly


root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/l*/*.MYI
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/loteriad_joomla/user_phocadownload.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/loteriad_joomla/user_phocadownload_user_stat.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/loteriad_joomla/user_session.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly


root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/m*/*.MYI
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/mfa_wp216/wp_options.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/mfa_wp216/wp_statistics_date.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
myisamchk: MyISAM file /var/lib/mysql/mfa_wp216/wp_statistics_visits.MYI
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly


root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state /var/lib/mysql/n*/*.MYI
myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/n*/*.MYI' doesn't exist
myisamchk: error: File '/var/lib/mysql/n*/*.MYI' doesn't exist
```

I tried following this link:

https://forums.cpanel.net/f49/mysql-databases-only-backup-293142.html#post12

They all save sql in one single directory. What would be the easiest, quickest way to remap them on the destination server with their respective username directories inside /var/lib/mysql/?

Got these errors when I ran above

```
root@server [~]# for i in `cat /root/mysql.txt`; do mysqldump $i >
/backup/db_backup/$i.sql; done
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_core_adi_aro';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_components';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_core_adi_aro';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'bak_components';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_components';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_core_adi_aro';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'sys_refindex'; try
to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table
'nuke_theme_tplfile'; try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_core_adi_aro';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'user_core_adi_aro';
try to repair it when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: Got error: 1034: Incorrect key file for table 'node'; try to
repair it when using LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repair affected database/table from phpmyadmin. phpadmin should available in cpanel home page.

1.Login to phpMyAdmin

2. Choose the affected database. If you only have one database, it should choose it by default so you don't need to do anything.
3. In the main panel, you should see a list of your database tables. Check the boxes by the tables that need repair.
4. At the bottom of the window just below the list of tables, there is a drop down menu. Choose "Repair Table"

and then you can transfer account successfully.